# Copy to clipboard using Zclipboard.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I tried Zclipboard.js for copying the value but it didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#copy-description').zclip({
        path:'ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:$('#description').text()

    });
});
</script>
<a id="copy-description" href="#" class="">Copy</a>
<p id="description">This should copy</p>
```

I referred it from [this](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/#) link. I am just getting a copy link with flash player embedded in it. But I cannot click it. What should I change in code, so that I can copy the description text on clicking copy link

Comment: `p#description` is not required. just use `#description`

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I changed it.. Not working

Comment: Sorry that wouldn't fix the problem :) it's just proper selector syntax.

Comment: Why not to used something like "Trello" there is no Flash movie involved check @ http://phatograph.github.io/blog/post/2013/08/15/how-does-trello-access-the-users-clipboard/

Comment: @JQueryGuru can you show me some working example of Trello? I cannot well understand what is shown in your link. Is that a jquery plugin, that solves user need of copying to clipboard by clicking any button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be the swf file. Try this. Hope it works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#copy-description').zclip({
        path:'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:$('#description').text()

    });
});
```

Comment: As expected .. It's not really nice to use steamdev.com as a hoster though ;)

Comment: yes... just pointing out the correct swf; the one that the original site makes use of...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the swf is loaded (using Firebug > Network) and that it is located above the link, as well with Firebug. Most likely the first one will solve your problem

Comment: Zeroclipboard.swf is loaded...But I think there is problem with code